# How to open a local HTML file in browser inside Unity3D game

Tags: html, ios, unity-game-engine, openurl

I'm struggling to open a local HTML file in a native iOS browser from my projects StreamingAssets folder. I'm trying to use `Application.OpenUrl(path)` but it doesn't work on any iOS device. Meanwhile it is opening this HTML file if I'm building for a standalone Mac or Windows (have not tried it for an Android build).

I must admit that I can read the raw file content (so I'm pretty sure that I have an access to this file) but when I'm trying to open the file after this, just nothing happens. :(

Comment: I've tested it with pdf and html files. Nothing happens when I'm calling Application.OpenUrl("file://" + path.Replace(" ", "%20")) using an iOS device, and everything works fine when building for standalone (pdf opens and html too).

Comment: Well, I've ended up with using prime31 Etcetera plugin. (Unity is as usual - helpless and bugged)